# Can we run multiple fb apps using just 1 sub-domain with SSL?

Tags: subdomain, ssl-certificate, facebook-apps

[I read all the similar questions previously answered, but the answers seemed rather conflicting. Please do only respond if you are 100% certain of the answer to prevent further confusion ;-) Thank you!]

We are planning to create facebook apps for clients.

Is it possible to use the same sub-domain for all apps in a way that requires a basic SSL certificate for all apps, so that a basic SSL certificate would suffice? (making it much more time and cost efficient for us)

If not, what would be the most time and cost efficient way to do it?

Using a wildcard SSL certificate?

Or a unified communication certificate?

And does anyone have a great recommendation where to best get the kind we need, obviously one acceptable by Facebook?

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You **can** point all of your applications to the same sub-domain and just have each application residing in a different folder.
As you said - you must ensure that this domain has an SSL certificate implemented on the server..

Comment: Correct.  I have in production multiple apps running off of the same subdomain.  I do have a real (not self-signed) SSL cert for the subdomain.  Check with your hosting provider to find out how the best way to achieve this might be.